# DatabaseChangeLog does not log rows with exectype other than "EXECUTED"

Tags: liquibase

I'm using Liquibase 3.8.0 to run migrations, and what I notice is that the DatabaseChangelog table only has rows with exectype "EXECUTED", meaning the migration is successful.

I've run a few migrations with errors but they do not appear in the DatabaseChangelog table. I would expect a few rows with exectype "FAILED". Am I missing an attribute? Sample changeSet:

```
    <changeSet id="TestFailOnError" author="myName">
        <sqlFile path="./TestFailOnError.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    </changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a changeset to have the value "FAILED" in the ExecType column of the DATABASECHANGELOG, but the only time that happens is when the changeset has a precondition with the "failOnError" attribute set to FALSE.

Normally when a changeset fails, that just stops the liquibase execution and it is expected that you will would fix the problem and then re-run the update command to deploy those changesets.